# Guzzle is ignoring base_uri

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm trying to connect an erp system's Rest API with Guzzle like this

```php
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'base_uri' => "{$this->getBaseUrl()}{$this->getClient()}/",
            'timeout' => 10,
            'auth' => [$this->getUsername(), $this->getPassword()],
            'headers' => $this->getHeader(),
        ]);

        $response = $client->request($this->getMethod(), $this->getUrl(), [
            'json' => $request,
        ]);
        return $response;
```

`$this->getBaseUrl()` returns http://ipaddressofclient:8080/mw/r/, `$this->getClient()` returns erp, so `base_uri` is http://ipaddressofclient:8080/mw/r/erp/, and I can confirm this while debugging.

Screenshot of variables while debugging

[image: Screenshot of variables while debugging]

`$this->getUrl()` returns `obj/data/2:1/query`, but I get a ConnectException with this message:

> cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: obj (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://obj:1/data/2:1/query

It seems like my base_uri is completely ignored. I'm using Guzzle 7.8.

What did I do wrong?

Edit: during debug, `$client->request()` looks like this:

Screenshot of variables

[image: Screenshot of variables]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the colon `:` is used in the path, which could be causing the issue. Try encoding the colon as `%3A` to avoid potential problems.

While the colon is a valid character in URLs, its presence in the path segment (as opposed to the protocol segment, like "http:") can be problematic.

Comment: This actually fixed my problem, simply wrapped `$this->url()` in `urlencode()`